# Azure data factory triggers still run after Deactivated

Tags: azure-data-factory

So even though my trigger shows a status of Stopped on Manage screen, the job still ran every 2 minutes, racking me up a very expensive bill

Do you really need to click Publish to confirm deactivating the trigger?  was that my mistake in understanding?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to click Publish to confirm deactivating the trigger, otherwise it would still run.

[image]